# What's the proof that the only Dedekind-complete field is the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, real-numbers, order-theory

I know that the field of the rational numbers is ordered but not Dedekind-complete. What's the proof that the only Dedekind-complete field is the reals?

Comment: Have you checked all the links stackexchange flags (on the right of your screen) as related?

Comment: I checked it and none of them explicitly asked for a proof.

Comment: @mathlander That's because is false: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936215/are-the-real-numbers-the-unique-dedekind-complete-ordered-set

Comment: I asked about fields, and the question you linked is about sets.